# Cancelling an upload task

Tags: c++, azure-blob-storage, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I've done some reading regarding the Azure SDK and in order to cancel a task you seemingly need to pass in a `cancellation_token`.

My upload code is very simple:

```
azure::storage::cloud_block_blob blockBlob = container.get_block_blob_reference(fileLeaf.wstring());

auto task = blockBlob.upload_from_file_async(fullFilePath);
```

However, some files I upload are potentially very large, and I would like to be able to cancel this operation.  I'll probably also likely use continuations and would need all those cancelling too, if that's possible.

The problem I'm having is I can't see any way of attaching a `cancellation_token` to the task.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a sample code using PPL library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984117.aspx#Canceling%20Parallel%20Tasks), I refered to it and changed the code for canceling task using PPLX library within C++ REST SDK which be used for Azure Storage SDK for C++, please try the code below.

```
/* Declare a cancellation_token_source and get the cancellation_token, 
 * please see http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classpplx_1_1cancellation__token__source.html
*/
#include <pplxtasks.h>
cancellation_token_source cts;
auto token = cts.get_token();

//Pass the cancellation_toke to task via then method, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj987787.aspx
task.then([]{}, token).wait();

// Cancel the task
cts.cancel();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks - passing the cancellation token into `then` was what I was missing, I ended up creating a task via `create_if_not_exists_async` then adding a then with a cancellation token in it.